# Function returning a random variable whose probability decreases with its value.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For my programming project I need a function that returns a **random variable X** of type **double** in range [1, +infinity>. This variable should follow a simple rule: the higher the value, the lower the probability of it being generated should be. For example, a value of 2.3 should have a much higher probability of being generated than 10.8. Similarly, 10.8 should have a higher probability than 534.1 being returned.

====================================================================

The variable **X** should follow this distribution:

The probability of **X** being in range <-infinity, 1> should be 0.

The probability of **X** being in range [1, +infinity> should be 1.

The probability of **X** being in range [2, +infinity> should be 0.5.

The probability of **X** being in range [3, +infinity> should be 0.3333...

The probability of **X** being in range [4, +infinity> should be 0.25.

...

**Generally, the probability of X being in range [x, +infinity] should be 1 / x, where x is any real number in range [1, +infinity>.**

How can I achieve such a function in any programming language?

Comment: I think I found your function. Note that the $\frac{\int_i^\infty f(x)dx}{\int_1^\infty f(x)dx} = 1/i$. This implies that $\int_i^\infty f(x)dx \propto 1/i$. Maybe you can think of a function that satisifies this?

Comment: This is the generic technique: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling . For your particular case : suppose $U \sim \mathrm{Unif}[0,1]$. What is the law of $1/U$?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thank you, this is helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that the function $f(t) = \frac{1}{t^2}$ over the space of $[1,\infty)$ is indeed a PDF: $$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t^2} \, dt = 1$$

Also see that $$\int_X^\infty \frac{1}{t^2} \, dt = \frac{1}{X}$$ for $X \gt 1$ in this case.

---

Now to find the CDF, notice that $$\int_1^X\frac{1}{t^2} \, dt =\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t^2} \, dt - \int_X^\infty \frac{1}{t^2} \, dt = \frac{X-1}{X} $$

Using the hint of inverse transform sampling in the link, generate a uniform random variable $u$ between $0$ and $1$ and solve the equation $$u = \frac{X-1}{X} \implies X = \frac{1}{1-u}$$

Therefore, you should generate your random variable, then substitute it into the above equation for $X$, and this $X$ is the sampled random variable that you are seeking from the given distribution

Comment: Hey @WaveX. Thanks for the answer! How can I use this knowledge to create a function in a programming language that satisfies the given criteria. I should have probably explained it better. Only tool in my programming language is that I have a function which can return a uniformly distributed value. How can I use this uniform random variable to get another value which has the probabilities as I explained in the original question?

Comment: See my edit $$ $$

Comment: Thank you kind sir!